# Get the row of current ul element

Tags: jquery, html

I have two ul elements which has the telerik autoComplete controls. So whenever I try to change the text of ul elements, onRowChange event it triggered, which initially retrieves the rowed, but in my case, if I try to change the text of First telerik autoComplete(first ul element) control, then I am not getting the current rowid.Instead of getting 0, I'm getting 1. Could you guys help me this. Thanks in advance
Below is the code:

```
<div id="ParentDiv" style="margin-bottom: -3% !important; margin-top: -3% !important">
               <ul style="" id="ChildUl_1" class="ChildUlClass_1">
                  <li style="margin-right: 12% !important"  class="ruleAutocomplete">
                    <label style="margin-left: -48% !important"> Rule <span class="astrik">*</span></label>                           
                      <div>
                        @(Html.Telerik().AutoComplete()
                                .Name("AutoComplete_1")
                                .BindTo((ViewData["Employee"]) as List<string>)
                                .Encode(true)
                                .AutoFill(true) 
                                .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("HRServices.onRuleChange"))
                                .HtmlAttributes(new
                                {                                      
                                    @autocomplete = "on"
                                })
                                .Filterable(filtering => filtering.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains)
                                .MinimumChars(3)))
                        </div>                  
                      </li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="" id="ChildUl_2" class="ChildUlClass_2">
          <li style="margin-right: 12% !important"  class="ruleAutocomplete">
                    <label style="margin-left: -48% !important"> Rule <span class="astrik">*</span></label>                           
                      <div>
                        @(Html.Telerik().AutoComplete()
                                .Name("AutoComplete_1")
                                .BindTo((ViewData["Student"]) as List<string>)
                                .Encode(true)
                                .AutoFill(true) 
                                .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange("HRServices.onRuleChange"))
                                .HtmlAttributes(new
                                {                                      
                                    @autocomplete = "on"
                                })
                                .Filterable(filtering => filtering.FilterMode(AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains)
                                .MinimumChars(3)))
                        </div>                  
                      </li>
```

Jquery:

```
HRServices.onRuleChange = function () {
    var row = $("#ParentDiv").find('ul');
    rowid = row.index();
    var selectedRowValue = $(row[rowid]).find("input[id^=AutoComplete_1]").val();

alert("You selected row Number"+rowid);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any part of your code relating to the "selected" or "current" row. The code just finds all the `<ul>` elements each and every time.

Comment: Yes, I am unable current selected ul, I am getting rowed as 5 if I put                                           var row = $("#RuleBasedDeliveryRouteDiv").find('ul :selected');
        rowid = row.index();